# Scale on one coordinate

Tags: graphics

I read many examples but I could not fix my code unfortunately.
Can you please help me and correct the code to extend x-axes so I can see the picture better.

```
s6 = ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. gam1[[1]], {t, 0, 250}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 0.5}, {0, 5}}, PlotPoints -> 7000], 
   AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
   PlotLabel -> 
    StyleForm["(d)", 
     Sequence[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontWeight -> "Bold", 
      FontSize -> 13]]];
Show[s6]
```

[image]
Thank you

Comment: try the option `AspectRatio -> 1`  in `Show` or in  `ParametricPlot`?

Comment: Thank you it works

Comment: Sounds like you got the problem solved, but still best to have questions with runnable code, and your isn't (`gam1` is undefined).

Comment: Yes, what is it that you are plotting?  And why did it show up squashed?  If you give some background, there may be more ways that surface of improving your plot ...